# How can I use the colours of a swatch in a script?

Tags: unity, c#, color

In Unity's editor I have set a swatch with some colours that are used throughout our game:

[image: The colour picker, with an added swatch of colours]

This swatch is saved in a file in the project's Assets folder:

```
\ProjectFolder\Assets\Editor\Main Colors.colors
```

I would like to use the colours in this swatch somewhere in a script:

```
GetComponent<Graphic>().color = SomethingHere.MainRed;
```

What is the best way to do this? Or is it not possible?

**Reflection**

I also think that I'm doing something really strange? I couldn't find any answer to this question online. But having the same colour library in the scripts as I use in the editor would be really nice.

Answer (score 2):

Better solution would be just to create ScriptableObject, with `List<Entry>`:

```
class Colors: ScriptableObject 
{
    [System.Serializable]    
    public class Entry 
    {
         public string name;
         public Color color;
    }

    public List<Entry> colors = new List<Entry>();

    public Color GetColor(string name) 
    { 
         var entry = colors.Find(c => c.name == name);
         if (entry != null) {
              return entry.color;
         }
         return Color.white;
    }
}
```

and later set that scriptable object anywhere you want.

```
Colors colors_db;
var color = colors_db.GetColor("MainRed")
```

Color preset you've saved is basically the same, but it's Editor only object.